# Rename the output file ArcGIS

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, file-geodatabase

I am copying a tons of features from a file geodatabase to a database server. First I created an enterprise geodatabase connenction and after a database connection. In the first step I added a database name. After I copy all the features from dekstop to this SQL Server Enterprise Geodatabase the features name modified with a prefix, which is the database name.

Someone know why and what is the best solution to delete all of this prefiex?

Comment: Database objects are *always* referenced by `owner.tablename` (Oracle) or `database.owner.tablename` (all others).  You cannot remove the owner or database from the name (doing so would prevent you from referencing the table).